# Chrome Dev Tools - print HTTP requests to console (like in Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox Dev Tools, you can open a 'Console' view and see HTTP requests together with logged statemenets like here:

[image: Firefox Dev Tools]

In Chrome, you can either have separate '**Console**' tab, or separate '**Network**' tab where you can see HTTP requests. Is there a way of combining those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own quesiton (sigh), but hopefully someone will find this useful..

So in Chrome you can click on little **gear** icon that brings you to settings. You can find 'Console' section there and tick 'Log XmlHttpRequests' (see picture)
[image]

Comment: talking about firefox, can we see http request in console like firefox in chrome?, in firefox we click and see the request without going to network tab @Xorty